# Django not recognizing user form email verification link:

Tags: html, django

I've spent the last week on this like 20 hours and can't figure it out. This is my very first Django application.

I have tested the 'urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))' in shell and it works to pass the user's 'uid', however it does not work in the application itself. I get that the 'activation link is invalid' for all links even though the link passed the correct primary key, I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Please help.

views.py/registration page

```
  from_email, subject = 'domain <info@domain>', 'Email verification'
  htmly = get_template('activation_email_template.html')
  username = user.username
  message = render_to_string('activation_email.html', {
                    'user':user,
                    'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                    'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
       })
  d = {'username': username, 'url':reverse('activate',
                kwargs={
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                'uidb64':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.uid))
                })}
  html_content = htmly.render(d) 
  msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, from_email,[user.email])
  msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
  msg.send()
```

here is my activate/views.py:

```
try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
       ...
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

For some reason I'm getting 'Activation Link is invalid' every time I try this. I know it's sending the right PK, because I can clink on the url and the url is correct with the correctly encoded pk. However, the activate view does not recognize this pk.

here is my activation_email.html:

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},
Thanks for creating an account. Please click on the link to confirm your registration,
http://domain{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

This is the activation_email_template:

```
<h3>Hi <strong>{{ username }}</strong>,</h3>
<p>Thanks for creating an account. Please click on the following link to confirm your registration:</p>
<a style="background-color: #f79407 ;padding: 10px 15px; text-decoration: none;color: #ffffff;text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 15px;" href="https://domain{{ url }}">Email Activation</a>
```

Please help!

Tried this to get at errors in activation link, but still just get activation link is invalid:

```
try:
    uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
    user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
except TypeError:
    print('typerror')
    user=None
except ValueError:
    print('valueerror')
    user=None
except OverflowError:
    print('OverflowError')
    user=None
except User.DoesNotExist:
    print('user.DoesNotExist')
    user=None
if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
.... 
else:
    raise ValidationError('user is none')
```

Comment: `http://domain{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}` what is in the domain ?

Comment: @arjun domain is just the domain of my site. I just haven't included that for privacy reasons. It works - it's www.mysite.com.

Comment: you are eating up the exceptions in `except` block and making `user=None`. If any exception is thrown then it will always go to `else` block. Can you please check if you are getting any exception in `activate/views.py` code? And because of that things are not working

Comment: I removed 'try' and 'except', still getting 'activation link is invalid'. I'll add what I did above.